# Can I change the value of `ORA_MAX_NAME_LEN`?

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

Can I change the value of  `ORA_MAX_NAME_LEN` with `alter` command or define a parameter when creating the database ? As in 12.2 its `128 bytes`.
I want to change it to `30 bytes`.
 Note: I dont want to change my COMPATIBLE version.

> Support for Longer Identifiers The maximum length of all identifiers
>   used and defined by PL/SQL is increased to 128 bytes, up from 30 bytes
>   in previous releases.
>
> If the COMPATIBLE parameter is set to a value of 12.2.0 or higher, the
>   representation of the identifier in the database character set cannot
>   exceed 128 bytes. If the COMPATIBLE parameter is set to a value of
>   12.1.0 or lower, the limit is 30 bytes.
>
> A new function ORA_MAX_NAME_LEN_SUPPORTED has been introduced to check
>   this limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. There are underlying c data structures which are allocated with that length. In addition it is required for PDB's to work correctly.